# How to use easy_install on linux terminal?

Tags: linux, python, easy-install

I am installing py2exe using `easy_install`. here is what I typed:

```
easy_install py2exe
```

I am using linux mint cinnamon 15. This is what I get, though:

> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test-easy->install-3460.pth'
>
> The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
> the distutils default setting) was:
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
>
> Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
> installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
> as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
> access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
> directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
> variable.
>
> For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
> documentation at:
>
> http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html
>
> Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

then I also tried pygame, but same error. can anyone help me install py2exe and report the problem? I am an administrator.

Comment: Use it with sudo, like `sudo easy_install py2exe`

Comment: just wanted to type that myself :D

Comment: @IOXenus - Why are you posting that as a comment?  Move to an answer to get the rep, especially since you're correct.  I may suggest adding a minor amount of info as to why if you have the time as well.

Comment: @nerdwaller I have posted this as a comment because I don't think that my answer is good/detailed enough. You're right, I was quite lazy at the time I answered. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use it with sudo, like:

`sudo easy_install py2exe`

In short, `sudo` is an awesome command that provides whatever you type after it with the root permissions. So you have enough permissions to install it with easy_install.

Comment: Sometimes the answer doesn't need to be a novel, thanks for posting it.  @techgenius101 - If you need more info on `sudo`, take a look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) or `man sudo` in your terminal.  It stands for "Super User Do".